# How can I check all pages are fully loaded in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

Is there anyway to check all components & elements are fully loaded in Polymer? Because I'm now planning to implement to execute or run background process in Polymer when all components & elements are fully loaded in Polymer. Please give me a hint way to implement as I said in Polymer.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. There probably isn't a way to find all elements used on a page let alone check whether they have been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Every Custom Element has an unresolved state until it's updated to the custom Shadow DOM. In Custom Elements v1 it's determined by the `:defined` pseudo-class, wich can be use to make list them with querySelector:

```
let undefinedElements = document.querySelectorAll(':not(:defined)');
console.debug('undefinedElements', undefinedElements);
```

Polymer 1.0 adding it's elements an `unresolved` attribute, because the v0 Api had that and it's also can be use:

```
let unresolvedElements = document.querySelectorAll('[unresolved]');
console.debug('unresolvedElements', unresolvedElements);
```

If you add `unresolved` attribute to your `body` then Polymer will fade in the page if every polymer element is updated to it's Shadow DOM.

> **NOTE**: I do not recommend to use `unresolved` on `body`, because it's blocking the first paint, and the user will leave after 3sec.  But add css rules to `my-element[unresolved]` to give it's size, color which will be after loaded and the user will will see only the elments updating but until that the page is working.

Comment: Not every custom element has an `unresolved` attribute.

Comment: All of the Custom Elements should have ```unresolved``` according the web components spec. If it's does not have then your browser is not implemented all of the spec requirements.

Comment: Where does the spec say that?

Comment: I dont know exactly where in the spec, it's in the one of the HTML Interface I belive, but I don't have time to search it and I trust in the Polymer team. I do know the [Custom Elements Unresolved State](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#unresolvedels) is in the Custom Element v1, and Polymer implements it.

Comment: Just [searched the spec](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=unresolved) myself (it only took a minute). There is **no reference to an `unresolved` attribute**. The link you mentioned describes an *unresolved state* and an `:unresolved` pseudo-class, but states nothing about an `unresolved` attribute existing in every custom element.

Comment: @tony19 I asked about it a bit, and you right. The custom elements v1 spec  the unresolved is now ```:not(:defined)``` > [Custom Elements v1 Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements?hl=en#prestyle) and it's in the spec also: https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#dom-elements